# Async Validator Doesn't Work on Angular AutoComplete

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want users to pick from autocomplete elements and when they even delete one character from the selected value, I want to show them an error and I also want my `FormControl` to be `invalid`. So far I couldn't figure it out. I'm also filtering the autocomplete values as the user types, and that [as can be seen here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200) causes the problem. The github issue seems to have `resolved` status but it still is a problem.

My `component.html` file:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>User</mat-label>
    <input
      placeholder="Pick one"
      matInput
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete
      autoActiveFirstOption
      #auto="matAutocomplete"
      [displayWith]="displayUserFn"
      (optionSelected)="valueChange('UserEntity', $event)"
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="option"
      >
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <span
    *ngIf="(myControl.touched || myControl.dirty) && (myControl.errors?.required || myControl.errors?.incorrect)"
    style="color: red"
  >
    User must be picked.
  </span>
</form>
```

My `component.ts` file:

```
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options = [
    {
      name: 'Johnny Depp',
    },
    {
      name: 'Jennifer Anniston',
    },
    {
      name: 'Jennifer Hernandez',
    },
    {
      name: 'John Cena',
    },
    {
      name: 'Jenny Something',
    },
    {
      name: 'Angelina Jolie',
    },
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myControl = new FormControl('', {
      validators: [Validators.required],
      asyncValidators: [this.requireMatch],
    });

    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) =>
        typeof value === 'string' ? this._filter(value) : [value]
      )
    );
  }

  requireMatch = (
    control: AbstractControl
  ): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    console.log(control);
    if (!control.valueChanges || control.pristine) {
      return of(null);
    } else {
      return this.filteredOptions.pipe(
        map((users) => {
          if (
            users.findIndex((user) => `${user.name}` === control.value) === -1
          ) {
            console.log('incorrect !');
            return { incorrect: true };
          }
          console.log('correct !');

          return null;
        })
      );
    }
  };

  private _filter(value) {
    if (value === null || value === '') return [];

    const loweredString = value.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US');

    return this.options
      .filter(
        (user) =>
          `${user.name}`.toLocaleLowerCase('en-US').indexOf(loweredString) !==
          -1
      )
      .sort((a, b) => `${a.name}`.localeCompare(`${b.name}`))
      .slice(0, 20);
  }
}
```

To clarify what I need:

When I write `je` and pick one value from the list:

[image]

[image]

It shouldn't show an error as there is an option with the same value of the input. But when alter the input value, I want to see an error, which I am not at the moment.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

I added these to a **stackblitz** project, can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qamtz-wkhl7t?file=src/app/autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html).

Comment: It's a known bug: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41519

Comment: It's a sad bug that dates back to 2016 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200 workarounds failed me so far for my usecase but haven't tried all of them. Should try the other ones I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41519), currently you'll have to poll the status to get what you want :

```
const ctrl = new FormControl();
const statusChanges$ = merge(ctrl.statusChanges, timer(0, 500)).pipe(
  map(() => ctrl.status),
  distinctUntilChanged()
);
```